# How to set Travis-CI deploy only release-* tags?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, github-pages

I have a question for Travis with Github-page.

I set up CI successful for build and deploy to Gh-page but that will deploy all commit.

```
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip-cleanup: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN
  target-branch: gh-pages
  local-dir: dist
  on:
    branch: master
```

In some documents I found, that said add `tags: true`, But that will set up Travis to build all tags when I push tags to master branch.

```
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip-cleanup: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN
  target-branch: gh-pages
  local-dir: dist
  on:
    branch: master
    tags: true
```

And I would like to build some specific tags like `release-*`, `dev-*`, `test-*`, so on...

So, How to config to do that with Travis.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can do it using Travis conditional in your yaml https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditions-v1

Comment: of course, that syntax is yaml config in .travis.yml file and I stuck when trying to config for build with specific tags... hmmm I already read that document   @MatthewBarlowe